# How to bulk update objects in a list

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects that I update:

```
membership_list = list(Memberships.objects.all())

for member in membership_list:
    member.status = var # could be 1/2/3 etc
    member.save()
```

However, this is very inefficient as with 100 memberships it hits the DB 100 times. Instead I want to use [`bulk_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update):

```
for member in membership_list:
    member.status = var # could be 1/2/3 etc
Memberships.object.bulk_update(membership_list)
```

However this obviously doesn't work, as the original list is not updated. What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

I could reconstitute the list, but this doesn't feel very DRY:

```
another_list = []
for member in membership_list:
    member.status = var # could be 1/2/3 etc
    another_list.append(member)

Memberships.object.bulk_update(another_list)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a *list*, but a `QuerySet`.

If the value is fixed, or an expression in terms of some other field(s), you can make use of [**`update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
Memberships.objects.all().update(status=1)
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
UPDATE memberships
SET status = 1
```

If you want to update objects with a more complex expression, you can first use a `list(…)` to materialize it:

```
membership_list = list(Membership.objects.all())
for member in membership_list:
    member.status = 1  # some expression
Memberships.object.bulk_update(membership_list, ['status'])
```

Comment: Thanks; apologies I wasn't clear that the status is a variable. Could I adapt this somehow?

Comment: @alias51: Yes, you can make use of a `list(..)` to "*materialize*" the objects.

Comment: Thanks. In your example, the list of membership objects wouldn't be updated with the new status would it? `bulk_update` calls the list from the first line?

Comment: @alias51: they will. If you for example use the index, it will set the status. There is a difference between a `QuerySet` (that will collapse to a (sub)query), and a list.

Comment: Ah, so any changes to objects in a list will be reflected when the list is called again.

Comment: @alias51: the `bulk_update` will, if you pass a list, use that list. The objects in that list are indeed updated.